# How do I group together all possible values of a set of discrete variables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, data-wrangling

I have a data frame with five dichotomous predictor variables, one dependent dichotomous variable, and a column of predicted probabilities:

```
  F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 Pred_Prob
1 A  D  E  G  I       0.25
2 B  C  F  H  J       0.3
3 A  C  E  G  I       0.9
4 B  C  F  H  J       0.4
5 B  C  F  H  J       0.2
6 A  D  F  G  I       0.7
```

I want to get the set of predicted probabilities for each possible combination of the dichotomous variables and then plot the probabilities in a box-and-whisker plot. How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.table(text="F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 Pred_Prob
      A  D  E  G  I       0.25
      B  C  F  H  J       0.3
      A  C  E  G  I       0.9
      B  C  F  H  J       0.4
      B  C  F  H  J       0.2
      A  D  F  G  I       0.7", header=TRUE)

 d2 <- dat %>% unite(id, -Pred_Prob)

 ggplot(d2) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=id, y=Pred_Prob))
```

[image]